# Standard ML polymorphic sorting

Tags: sorting, polymorphism, sml

I am very inexperienced in ML, and I just can't make sense of this.

**Start question**

Polymorphic Sorting

This function performing insertion sort on a list takes as arguments a comparison function less and a list l of elements to be sorted. The code compiles and runs correctly:

```
fun sort(less, nil) = nil |
    sort(less, a : : l) =
       let

fun insert(a, nil) = a : : nil |
   insert(a, b : : l) = if less(a,b) then a : : (b: : l)
                                   else b : : insert(a, l)

in
    insert(a, sort(less, l))
end;
```

What is the type of this sort function? Explain briefly, including the type of the subsidiary function insert. You do not have to run the ML algorithm on this code; just explain why an ordinary ML programmer would expect the code to have this type. (**End of question**)

I've gotten the type of the sort function (by running the code in an SML interpreter), but I just can't get the second part about insert.

Type of sort function:

```
val sort = fn : ('a * 'a -> bool) * 'a list -> 'a list
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you discovered the type of `sort` in an SML REPL why didn't you do the same for `insert`? In any event -- this looks like homework. If so, the text for the course should have a fairly detailed discussion of SML's type system. Did you read it?  You have reproduced a question but didn't ask any question of your own, at least not a question which demonstrates any effort on your part.

Comment: I have read it, and I don't understand it (which is why I came here). Also, I did put in the insert function into the compilier and I got this          `fun insert(a, nil) = a :: nil |
insert(a, b :: l) = if less(a,b) then a :: (b :: l)
else b :: insert(a,l)`

Comment: I typed in the `fun insert` part and it says `stdIn:9.24-9.28 Error: unbound variable or constructor: less`

Comment: But what is the *type* of the function `insert` from the compiler? Also -- what, exactly, do you not understand about what you have been reading? What parts of e.g. `fn : ('a * 'a -> bool) * 'a list -> 'a list ` is giving you a problem?

Comment: Why not provide a definition of `less` first?

Comment: Is the type for `insert` the same type for `sort`? I don't know a definition for `less` (I am really new to this).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104820/discussion-between-user3313728-and-john-coleman).

Comment: The type of `insert` is `'a * 'a -> bool`. You can use a dummy function like `fun insert (x,y) = false;` if all you want is to get it to compile. Unfortunately -- the real world calls and I have to log off now. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

That you figured out the type of `sort` by "cheating" makes the next step harder; don't take shortcuts.
(Nobody ever learned anything by peeking at the answer.)

But here's how you could figure out `insert`:

You know from

```
val sort = fn : ('a * 'a -> bool) * 'a list -> 'a list
```

that the second argument to `sort` is an `'a list`.

In

```
insert(a, sort(less, l))
```

you can see immediately that it has some type `(X * Y) -> Z` for *some* `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.

You're passing the first element of `sort`'s second argument - `a` - as `insert`'s first argument.
Since `sort`'s second argument is an `'a list`, that list's first element is an `'a`.
So `X` is `'a`, and we now know that `insert` is `('a * Y) -> Z` for *some* `Y` and `Z`.

The type of `insert`'s second argument - `sort(less, l)` - is well known; it's `'a list`.
So we now know that `Y` is `'a list`, and `insert` is `('a * 'a list) -> Z` for *some* `Z`.

All that remains is the return type, and since

```
insert(a, sort(less, l))
```

is what `sort` returns, it must have the same return type as `sort`.
So `Z` is `'a list`.

In summary, `insert`'s type is

```
('a * 'a list) -> 'a list
```

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that it is "cheating" to see what type ML infers since the emphasis seems to be on *explaining* the meaning of the type. For a beginner it is hard to even parse something like `('a * 'a -> bool) * 'a list -> 'a list `, let alone give a cogent explanation of what it means.